# How to find days between two dates with time in jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery, how do I get the number of days between two dates with time also.

```
var fromDate = $("#from_txn_date").val();//2017-02-20 00:00:00
var toDate = $("#to_txn_date").val();//2017-06-20 00:00:00
```

my date format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

How to check days? i tried but time reason i didn't get solutuion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3224854/1719752

Comment: What is Google?